# SqlException при переносе проекта на другой ПК

Tags: sql, ado.net

При переносе проекта с одного ПК на другой, возникло SqlException, я проверил работоспособность проекта на первом ПК и всё вновь работает, но на втором ничего не работает. На обоих стоит SqlExpress 2012.

> Дополнительные сведения: Истекло время ожидания соединения. Время
>   ожидания истекло на этапе после входа. Возможно, время ожидания
>   соединения истекло, пока сервер выполнял процесс входа в систему и
>   отправки ответа, или это произошло при попытке создать несколько
>   активных соединений.  Время, затраченное на попытки подключиться к
>   этому серверу, составило: [Pre-Login] initialization=634;
>   handshake=1827; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=46;
>   [Post-Login] complete=13069;

Строка подключения:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="userStore" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataBase\UserStore.mdf;User Instance=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: у меня была похожая проблема, выяснилось, что конфигурации SQLExpress расходятся, советую проверить весь установленный функционал как следует

Comment: Проверь имя сервера Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Проверьте логи сервера (хотя бы в Event Log). Судя по ошибке, подключение оборвалось на Post-login, так что сервер должен был записать конкретное сообщение в лог.

Comment: @Алексей, вы решили свою проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте установить Connection Timeout = 30. В результате должно получится следующая строка подключения:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="userStore" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=30;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataBase\UserStore.mdf;User Instance=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```